# reactstrap + bootstrap 4 beta dropdown won't work

Tags: drop-down-menu, nav, create-react-app, reactstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4-beta

I don't understand why this nav dropdown doesn't work.  My reading suggests it might have something to do with adding the react-popper dependency but I don't really understand how this is to be implemented.  This is bootstrap 4 beta + create-react-app + reactstrap 5.0.0-alpha.4.  Following the reactstrap [documentation](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap).

My [Git repo link](https://github.com/DavidWallJ/basic-reactstrap-app)

The bootstrap code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light mb-3">
                <div className="container">
                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        Navbar
                    </a>
                    <button
                        className="navbar-toggler"
                        data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbarNav"
                    >
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                                    Home
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                                    About
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                                    Services
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                                    Contact
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

dependencies package.json:

```
{
  "name": "basic-reactstrap-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-popper": "^0.7.4",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```